# Draw route direction from current location to destination in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, routes, gps, maps

I can get mobil device's location. And destination is constant location. How can I draw route direction from current location to destination in Unity3d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Ralph Barbagallo's Blog on Displaying Maps in Unity3D](http://ralphbarbagallo.com/2013/02/19/displaying-maps-in-unity3d/). It would be helpful